# Way to check if rectangle contains anything (without passing the "anything" as a parameter)

Tags: c++, sfml

Using it for a chess game, i want the tiles to be able to tell if anything is on it without the function passing the other object as a parameter so it can see if the tile global bounds of the tile contains the global bounds of the other object. The only objects in those tiles will be the chess piece anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "tile" and "global bounds"? I thought chess contains squares only. How is this question specific to SFML?

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of GameMaker's [`instance_place()`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_place.html) function, that's able to retrieve any existing object that's colliding with something.

Unfortunately, there is no way to query "all of the existing objects" in C++. First that would be **way** too many objects, but also, most of them don't have spatial information at all (how do you check for collisions with `std::cout` ?)

However you go about it, you have to pass the list of pieces to your function somehow, so it can iterate through it and find whether one intersects. Some ways are:

### Parameter passing

```
Piece *Tile::findCollision(PieceList &pieces);
```

... or its more `<algorithm>`-flavoured counterpart:

```
template <class Ite>
Ite Tile::findCollision(Ite first, Ite last);
```

Both would return an iterator (pointer) to the colliding `Piece`, or `last` (`nullptr`) if none is. That is the solution you wish to avoid, but is the most idiomatic.

### Class member

The `Chessboard` class would contain `PieceList _myPieces` as a member variable, which could then be accessed from within the function:

```
// Accesses this->_myPieces
Piece *Chessboard::findPiece(Tile const &position);
```

### Global variable

Global state is generally frowned upon, but is still technically a solution : you'd make your `PieceList chessPieces` globally accessible, and then access it from the function:

```
// No parameter, invisibly accesses some global state somewhere :(
Piece *Tile::findCollidingPiece();
```

### Capturing

That one would be quite unusual. You can capture the `PieceList` by reference inside a lambda, and store it for future use.

```
PieceList chessPieces;
auto findCollidingPiece = [&chessPieces](Tile const &position) -> Piece* { /*...*/ };
```

---

### Is that necessary at all?

But all of these deal with real-space collisions. While they are applicable here, the better idea would be to acknowledge the grid-based nature of chess in your design, and do everything with integer coordinates and no collision checking. You'd store a 2D array of `std::unique_ptr<Pieces>` inside your `Chessboard` class, which would expose the function:

```
Piece *Chessboard::pieceAt(int x, int y);
```

A `Tile`, if you actually needed one, would store its integer coordinates and the `Chessboard &` it belongs to, and access the latter for any queries, effectively acting as a proxy.